# Kotlin string exists but can't use almost all string functionality

Tags: kotlin

Summary: I have a string from which I can print and use substring, but can't use attributes such as length or functions such as .toInt() or .compareTo(), why would this be the case?

```
var s = "20"
val myToast = Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
myToast.show()
//20

val myToast2 = Toast.makeText(this, s.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
myToast2.show()
//The app crashes with the error: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
```

I can call substring on string s, but I can't call length, toInt(), compareTo(), etc.

The string clearly exists since I can print it and use substring but if that is true why does my app throw an error when I try to use other attributes and functions from it?

Comment: Isn't the problem that you are passing an integer to `Toast.makeText` and so it looks for a resource by id?

Comment: @wobr Where am I passing an int? s is a string as far as I am aware.

Comment: Edit, figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two overloads of `Toast.makeText()`. One accepts a `String` as the second argument, and displays that string. The other accepts an `Int` as the second argument, and displays whatever string resource has that integer id. (Normally you'd pass something like `R.string.my_string` here.)

When you call `.length` on your String, you'll get an Int back. And that means you wind up calling the second overload, which then looks for a string resource with the id `2`. That doesn't exist, so you crash.

If you want to just display the number 2, then you need to make this a String again. You can use `.toString()` or `"${s.length}"`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Add .toString at the end of length,toInt(),compareTo(), etc. because s.length
return int :not String

Here is your modified answer
`var s = "20"`
`val myToast = Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)`
`myToast.show()`
//20

`val myToast2 = Toast.makeText(this, s.length.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)`
`myToast2.show()`